# AutoFac for Window Phone 7 - IContainter.Resolve extension method is not found

Tags: windows-phone-7, autofac

I'm building a fun application for Windows Phone 7. I'm using MVVM pattern and AutoFac for resolving the dependencies. I have got a classes `AutoFacConfiguration` holding a property as below

`public static IContainer Container { get; private set; }`

I try to resolve one of the registered types in some other part of the application like below

`AutoFacConfiguration.Container.Resolve<IExpenseRepository>()`

But this is not compiling. The compiler says Container does not have `Resolve` method. I know that `IContainer` derives from `IComponentContext` and an extension method with following signature does existing in the AutoFac assembly

`public TService Resolve<TService>(this IComponentContext context)`

Am I missing something here? I have just referenced the AutoFac.dll in my porject. This is downloaded from autofac site.

Comment: Jon seems to be on the right track below, but could we see some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the relevant namespace as a `using` directive? For example, if the extension method is in class Foo.Bar.Baz, you should have:

```
using Foo.Bar;
```

in the source file that's trying to use the extension method.

Comment: I have added `using AutoFac` and the namespace where the class `AutoFacConfiguration` is defined. I doubt that could be the reason though I double checked that.

Comment: @Suhas: You need it in the code which *uses* the extension method. If that doesn't help, try calling the extension method explicitly - what class is it declared in?